# How to use SAP designer combine multiple rows to one cell

Tags: database, sap-data-services

How to use SAP designer combine multiple rows into one cell?

My source table is like below:

```
|        Col_A        |       Col_B      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |         A        |  
|          1          |         B        |  
|          1          |         C        |  
|          2          |         D        |   
|          2          |         E        |
```

And my target will like below:

```
|       Col_A         |      Col_B       |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|          1          |      A,B,C       |   
|          2          |       D,E        |
```

Is that any tools can I use in SAP Data Services

Answer (score -1):

for a while I found the answer

https://blogs.sap.com/2012/12/08/bods-concatenate-custom-function/

and if you want split the data by comma use this

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EIM/How+to+split+a+comma+separated+String+into+multiple+rows+via+word_ext

Comment: As per Stack Overflow guidelines, add an excerpt of the solution instead of just linking to another Web site.